# Unity. Unload DLL at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, .net-assembly

So, currently I have a dll that is loaded when the application starts. I have both used

```
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(DLLData.LocalDLLFolder() + "DLLSupport.dll", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());

                    Type _main = assembly.GetType("DLLSupport.DebugStart");

                    dllSupport = new GameObject();
                    dllSupport.AddComponent(_main);

                    memoryStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

and `Assembly.LoadFrom`

The thing is that when is running I will download this same DLL again if its updated.
If I try to download it with Assembly.LoadFrom It wont allow me since the file is being used by Unity.

With the other method I can download or delete it when I want, but the thing is that even if I call that method again it will work like the previous one until I restart the application. (Maybe there is any way to unload that that I didnt found?)

I tried it too with AppDomain but I will get `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies`

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot unload an assembly from the curren AppDomain, but you can create an AppDomain, and load assembly into it, execute some codes on that AppDomain, and then Unload the AppDomain when necessary, this will also Unload the assembly on that domain.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms173101(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but as I said I get that last error